# Can I have EC2 instance within the same vpc have a different availability zone

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, subnet

I wonder if it is possible to have one single instance running in a different AZ than its peers within the same private subnet of another AZ. There is a database cluster private subnet in which my shard and replication instances run. I want to put my replication instances to different AZs just so my database won't be down if current AZ is not available. I noticed that I can launch new instances in new subnets which could be in a different AZ. But is it possible that I have all these instances reside within the same private subnet but only changing some of these instances' AZs?

Comment: Why do you need them in one subnet?

Answer (score 2):

No.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-subnet-basics

> Each subnet must reside entirely within one Availability Zone and cannot span zones.